# How to query a table in SQLAlchemy that you didn't create (was already on the database)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask and MYSQL in general, for a school assignment I have to make a simple website which interacts with a database that I created at school.

I am using Flask to create the website, I have already verified that I was able to connect to the SQL database because I was able to add a "Test" table that showed up on phpMyAdmin.

The issue that I am having is that I am unable to query any of the tables that I didn't create, I know that I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("test1.html")

@app.route('/profile/<name>')
def profile(name):
    return render_template("profile.html", name=name )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(db.Query(movie.query.filter_by(year_of_release=1972)))
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

The "Test" table showed on phpMyAdmin when I ran db.create_tables(), however the error I am getting is **"NameError: name 'movie' is not defined"**

If someone could point me in the right direct that would be great, thanks.

Comment: Try to access table using `<database name>.<tablename> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are accessing a table in The class should have a attribute

```
__tablename__ = 'movies'
```

For the SQLAlchemy class to point to a table you would have to tell SQLAlchemy which class points to which table. So if the table name is `'movies'` then in your class you should use `__tablename__ = 'movies'`

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a little further? Do I need to do something like ```Class movies(db.Model):``` ?

Comment: Yes. You have add the table name attribute to your model class